# How to partition so as to install more Linux Distributions

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

I have the following partitions:

- sda1 ntfs recovery 7GB (boot, diag)
- sda2 ntfs windows 40 GB
- sda3 ext3 linux 12 GB
- sda4 extended 55 GB

  - sda6 ext3 work 53 GB
  - sda5 swap 2GB

I tried to shrink the windows partition to something like 24 GB so as to create two more partitions of 8 GB each, where I would like to install many Linux Distributions. But gparted didn't allow me to do so because there are already 4 primary partitions. What should I do? (Also, I don't understand which are the primary partitions in the above list? I guess sda1, sda2, sda3 are primary.) I can maybe shrink windows to 24 GB, and use the 16 GB space for work but I don't know where the new distributions will go to.

How can I do add more?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your partition map, `sda4` is your extended partition and `sda6` and `sda5` seem to be `logical` partitions within it.

Now, since you already have 4 primary partitions (**including** `sda4`, which is considered so too), you cannot define a new primary partition. Shrinking `sda1` to split it is going to fail for this reason.

You have a couple of simple options to pick from.
(all of them are based on getting more space in your `extended` partition).

1. Shrink your data partition `sda6` to create more logical partitions. 
   You can install unix based systems on these logical partitions, things like `GRUB` can handle this.
2. Kill or move-out your unix partitions (`sda3` and `sda6`) and then restructure your disk.

   - This implies you either backup your unix data to be restored in a fresh install or backup entire partition image to be restores (provided you have some experience doing that).
   - If you do this, you will have an intermediate state where `sda1` and `sda2` would be the only useful partitions on your system.
   - At such time, you can also go ahead to shrink your `sda2` and release more free space into unallocated area (you would have already deleted the other partitions).
   - Now, you can create a single extended partition of all available free space and start with new partitions within it where you will reinstall or recover your primary unix partition (which is `sda3` now) and then add in other unix systems as you choose.

Remember, you can share a single `swap` partition across all your unix systems. This is because you won't be running more than one at a time and that running system can use the common `swap` partition. The `swap` partition has no persistent data across reboots.

When you boot into Unix, try the command "`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`".
It will dump your partition table with the `sda4` described as `Extended` and its `Start` and `End` range will encompass that of the remaining (`sda6` and `sda5`) logical partitions. This `Extended` partition is also counted as a `primary partition`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me pointers to the first part of your second point - backing up the unix partition and restoring it later.